# Can I have if statements that operate on UI that is triggered at the same time?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build a simple app with two modes. The user can leave 'non-interactive-mode' by flicking a switch. This generates some new UI elements, and produces a result based on the values in the UI element.

For some operations this works fine, but my `if` statements throw `Warnings` at the first time I run the code (`Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero`). I think I understand why this is happening (the input doesn't exist the first time the code reads the if block), but can it be worked around in a simple way?

MWE below:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  materialSwitch(inputId = "interactive", label = "Interactive?",value=FALSE),
  uiOutput("on_interactive_only"),
  uiOutput("result_output")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Non-interactive Result
  output$result_output <- renderUI(if(!input$interactive){
    (renderTable(data.frame('dummy'=1:3)))})
  
 # If interactive we need another UI element
  output$on_interactive_only <- renderUI(if(input$interactive){
    numericInput("value_to_specify",'Which Number?',5)})
  
  # And now we need to react to that value
  output$result_output <- renderUI(if(input$interactive){
    if(input$value_to_specify > 3){
    (renderTable(data.frame('dummy'=input$value_to_specify)))}})
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Try `req(input$value_to_specify)` to "require" that the value exists before proceeding. You should be able to use that in the `if` itself. Please include all relevant `library()` commands for your example; `materialSwitch` doesn't seem to be a part of `shiny`.

Comment: Thanks, I've made the edit to the question and will try out req() now.

Comment: Try observeEvent() -- https://mastering-shiny.org/reactivity-components.html

Comment: `conditionalPanel` should solve your troubles.
See the [examples](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/conditionalPanel.html).